# конфликт имени max - Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Как исправить конфликт имени max в данном примере?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <limits>


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определить до включения `windows.h` макрос  `NOMINMAX`

```
#define  NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <limits>


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а если нужно MINMAX тоже, в смысле, нужен и макрос min и max

Comment: В смысле, нужны эти функции? включите `#include <algorithm>` и пользуйтесь... Если нужны **именно макросы** - то, как говорится в анекдоте - нужно выбирать, или крестик снять, или трусы надеть... :)

Comment: словом нельзя объявлять макросы именами используемыми в стандартной библиотеке, даже если они защищены пространством имен?

Comment: Макросы тем и ужасны, что **ничего не знают** ни о каких пространствах имен, классах или функциях. Они вообще ничего не знают о языке! Это просто тупая замена текста до начала компиляции...